# stm32 Run time error caused by Global variable extern const char*

Tags: c, linker, stm32, extern

I get a runtime error "Hard Fault" due to the following code:

FileA.c

```
const char* globalfilepath = "/path/to/folder";
```

FileB.c

```
extern const char* globalfilepath;
void my_function(){
{ ...
    // Hard fault right here, debugger shows variable is empty string
    FILE* fd = open(globalfilepath);
...}
```

It compiles without warnings, the issue happens only at runtime. I'm compiling with no optimization.

Comment: Which of these code lines are actually inside functions?

Comment: The open file portion is inside a function call.

Comment: Is `globalfilepath` present in the map file? It should be located in RAM. Are you running the start-up ("CRT") code for initializing it? What happens if you move the pointer to flash instead? That is: `const char globalfilepath[] = "..."`

Comment: That did resolve the issue. But can you explain a little what happens?

Comment: I don't know, your RAM variables are acting up or not getting linked for whatever reason. Check the map file before and after the change, see where the variable got allocated.

Comment: Wait, so you're declaring a pointer to a constant character, and the value of this pointer is an array of characters? A pointer is supposed to hold an address, not a string. Try creating a char array (string), the name of the array itself is a pointer. Try to pass that and see what happens.